# New column in Pandas Dataframe where values depend on previous rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a Pandas Dataframe of fixtures from a football league in chronological order, like this:

```
       Wk        Date            Home  xGHome  GFHome  Result  GFAway  xGAway            Away
0     1.0  2017-08-11         Arsenal     2.1       4       1       3     1.6  Leicester City
1     1.0  2017-08-12         Watford     2.0       3       0       3     3.0       Liverpool
2     1.0  2017-08-12       West Brom     1.2       1       1       0     0.4     Bournemouth
3     1.0  2017-08-12         Everton     0.4       1       1       0     0.3      Stoke City
```

I would like to add new columns: PtsHome and PtsAway, which would represent number of points a team had won before the game happened. So in the first round everyone would be at 0 points, in 2nd round teams who won their first game would be at 3 points, teams who drew at 1 etc.

How do I properly do this? Values in PtsHome & PtsAway column depend on values from filtered multiple previous rows to which a function is applied, that's the abstract problem I'm struggling with.

Comment: is the Wk column representive of the Round?